# Fetching data from another device

Tags: java, android, networking

I'm working on an shopping list app where all the family can connect to the same list.
How can i make and save the list on one device and then connect from all the devices to the list?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the concept of Websockets.

> WebSockets represent a long awaited evolution in client/server web technology. They allow a long-held single TCP socket connection to be established between the client and server which allows for bi-directional, full duplex, messages to be instantly distributed with little overhead resulting in a very low latency connection.

Thats means if you create a server with a web socket connection, and you allow other clients(android) to connect to that connection. You can send messages back and forth and every device connected will recieve it. All connected is how i like to call it. Think socket.io and node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fetch the device data without having a medium or **network** in between them and if you choose **Bluetooth** or **wifi** then your data will be **local** and other family member living another city won't be able to contribute. so at last if i'm guessing right you need a synchronised database which can give you realtime updates from another user.

This is where [Firebase Realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) comes in. you can use it in your project, it's easy and takes few minutes to configure.
since all the user will have their own app they can contribute to same database and others can see it instantly.
Read the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) for android